# Opposite of ondragover in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a drag and drop application for which the user drags a file into a div. When the file that is being dragged is over the div, the div turns green.

```js
var dropzone = document.querySelector(".dropzone");

dropzone.ondragover = event => {
  event.target.classList.add("fileover");
};
```

```css
.dropzone {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.fileover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" style="display: none"/>
<label for="file">
  <div class="dropzone" ondrop="event.preventDefault()">Drag and drop or select a file</div>
</label>
```

But let's say, the user decides not to drop the file into the drop zone and moves the file away from the drop zone. In that case, the drop zone stays green. So is there an event that fires when the file goes away the drop zone, so then, the drop zone turns white again? Something like `ondragaway`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ondragleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondragleave) :

Note that I also replace `ondragover` with [`ondragenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragenter_event) for the sake of consistensy.

```js
var dropzone = document.querySelector(".dropzone");

dropzone.ondragenter = event => {
  event.target.classList.add("fileover");
};

dropzone.ondragleave = event => {
  event.target.classList.remove("fileover");
};
```

```css
.dropzone {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.fileover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" style="display: none"/>
<label for="file">
  <div class="dropzone" ondrop="event.preventDefault()">Drag and drop or select a file</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Also, why `dragcenter` instead of `dragover`?

Comment: `dragover` happens every few hundred milliseconds, while `dragcenter` only fires once. It's better to use `dragcenter`.